# I can't get my Javascript Login Form to work

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to learn Java to apply to HTML. 
As an exercise I'm trying to create a Signup form that would create a username, and then a Login page that will take input for the username and compare it to the Username enter in the Signup. But Im getting an error, saying that the userName that I had created as a variable in the signup page is not defined.

My guess is that the login form is not having access to that variable, but I can't figure out how to send information from one form to the other.

Any ideas?

```js
//SIGNUP SCRIPT
    document.getElementById("signup-button").onclick = function() {
        var userName = document.getElementById("signup-username").value;
        var passWord = document.getElementById("signup-password").value;
        console.log(userName) //THI IS JUST TO CHECK CONSOLE AND MAKE SURE THAT THE USERNAME IS BEING REGISTERED 
        console.log(passWord)
    }
    
    //LOGIN SCRIPT
    document.getElementById("login-button").onclick = function() {
        if ( document.getElementById("signup-username").value == userName) {
            alert("loged in")
        }
        else alert("You enter the wrong username!")
        }
```

```css
  body {
        background-color: black;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        font-family: "Helvetica";     
    }
    
    #form {
        width: 400px; 
        height: 300px;
        border: 1px white solid;
        color: white;
        margin: 50px auto;
    }
    
    #form-content {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    
    #username {
        width: 200px;
        text-align: right;
    }
    
    #password {
        width: 200px;
        text-align: right;
    }
    
    .button {
        margin: 30px 0 0 10px;
        padding: 5px 20px;
        width: 50px;
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
    }
    
    .button:hover {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        border: 2px white solid; 
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<!--SIGN UP FORM-->
    <div id="form">
        <div id="form-content">
            <h1>Sign Up</h1>
            <p id="username">Username: <input type="text" id="signup-username" value="Enter your username or email."></p>
            <p id="password">Password: <input type="text" id="signup-password" value="Enter your password."></p>
            <p id="signup-button" class="button">Submit</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <!--LOG IN FORM-->
    <div id="form">
        <div id="form-content">
            <h1>Log in</h1>
            <p id="username">Username: <input type="text" id="login-username" value="Enter your username or email."></p>
            <p id="password">Password: <input type="text" id="login-password" value="Enter your password."></p>
            <p id="login-button" class="button">Submit</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`username` and `password` are scoped to the function they are declared in - you either need to do

```
document.getElementById("signup-button").onclick = function() {
    window.userName = document.getElementById("signup-username").value;
    window.passWord = document.getElementById("signup-password").value;
    console.log(userName) //THI IS JUST TO CHECK CONSOLE AND MAKE SURE THAT THE USERNAME IS BEING REGISTERED 
    console.log(passWord)
}
```

or

```
var userName;
var passWord;
document.getElementById("signup-button").onclick = function() {
    userName = document.getElementById("signup-username").value;
    passWord = document.getElementById("signup-password").value;
    console.log(userName) //THI IS JUST TO CHECK CONSOLE AND MAKE SURE THAT THE USERNAME IS BEING REGISTERED 
    console.log(passWord)
}
```

Comment: Dude, you are amazing! I can't believe you answered so fast. 
I see what the problem is, I think I like the second option more, will try with that one.

Comment: Ok, I tried it and it works, just have one more issue. 
I always get the alert for a True statement. Even when entering a wrong password, the "else" statement doesn't seem to run.